# Find duplicate words containing a character across a file in Notepad++

Tags: regex, duplicates, notepad++

I have found many solutions online where consecutive duplicate words or even duplicate words in one line, but I have never found a working way to get:

**Duplicate words across the whole file that contain a character.**

For my case, the character would be "_".

So in this excerpt

```
#define 35441 FF_EIS_DMC_1_TERRAIN_FROM //Terrain update from time
#define 35442 FF_EIS_DMC_1_TERRAIN_AHEAD_TIME //Terrain ahead activation time
#define 35442 FF_EIS_DMC_1_TERRAIN_AHEAD_TIME_DATE //Terrain ahead activation time and date
#define 35443 FF_EIS_DMC_1_TERRAIN_FROM //Terrain update from time
#define 35521 FF_EIS_DMC_1_BUS_1 //ARINC Data Bus 1
#define 35522 FF_EIS_DMC_1_BUS_1_DATA_BUS //Data Bus failure
```

i would like to find the second occasion of `FF_EIS_DMC_1_TERRAIN_FROM`.

Last spec I'd like to add: I got Notepad++ and since I want to make this a prozess that anyone can use I'd like to execute this without any addons or other programs.

Is this possible and if so, how?

Comment: `\b(FF\S+)\b.*\K\1` with `s` flag?

Comment: Veeeery close already, thanks! Only problem now (which I didn't state properly in my question, my bad!) is that I have words that might start with the same string but end differently. See updated question for example -> "... AHEAD_TIME" and "AHEAD_TIME_DATE" would be marked by the regex you suggested.

Comment: [My regex still matches that correctly](https://regex101.com/r/8OKzTe/1) :)

Comment: Indeed... Okay, I don't understand enough of regex though I'm trying hard right now but what it does not do is recognize that there might be a duplicate when it ends with a number: https://regex101.com/r/8OKzTe/2 Thanks btw for your help so far!

Comment: Ok, I now understand your problem. I posted my regex as an answer fixing the issue you mention in your comment. It just needed to be appended `\b`.

Answer (score 0):

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/8OKzTe/3)

```
\b(FF\S+)\b.*\K\1\b
```

- `\b` Assert position as a word boundary
- `(FF\S+)` Capture `FF` followed by any non-whitespace characters one or more times into capture group 1. You can replace `\S` with `\w` if you're only dealing with `a-zA-Z0-9_`.
- `\b` Assert position as a word boundary
- `.*` Matches any character any number of times. With the `s` flag, this also matches `\n`
- `\K` Resets the starting point of the reported match. Any previously consumed characters are no longer included in the final match
- `\1` Matches the text that was most recently matched by the 1st capture group
- `\b` Assert position as a word boundary

[image: Notepad++ regex screenshot]

Comment: I see it working on regex101 but in Notepad++ it just highlights the whole text. :/

Comment: I'm sorry for coming back all the time without any approaches to a solution:(

Comment: @Maverick283 I added an image to my answer that includes the regex settings for Notepad++. Ensure your settings are identical. Notice it'll highlight both the captured and matched text, but it only shows one occurrence. That's because it'll only actually *match* the second occurrence (the line has a subtle blueish purple tint highlighting it), while the first green-highlighted text is the first capture group, only used to identify the second occurrence. A replace will only affect the *matched* text and leave the capture group unaffected :)

Comment: Hm, something is still not working but thank you very much for your help so far. If i figure out whats wrong on my end and it still not works I'll come back here,hoping you're still willing to help, but thank you so much!